# Android Connecting to Xamp

Tags: android, xampp

Good day.I am trying to connect my android application to xamp. Basically I have an application that uses xamp, it works on an emulator but not on the actual device.After hours of searching, I found solutions to use tethering on usb and wifi. With tethering I get the error "adb problem, unable to communicate with device..please kill add".With wifi, it does not access my localhost.I know that someone might say this is a broad question.What I am asking is, how can I make my device access my xamp localhost?

I just mentioned the above to show what I tried and could not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

If your android device and the device running XAMPP, are both on the same network, you could just use the private IP address of the machine running XAMPP, but if they're not on the same network, then you are gonna need to do some port forwarding and maybe get a static IP address.